# Swift floating-point number and cpu architecture

Tags: ios, swift

I search a lot about CGFloat, Float and Double in swift, but still not fully understand:

1. From Apple doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html

> Double represents a 64-bit floating-point number.
>
> Float represents a 32-bit floating-point number.

So in 32-bit CPU architecture, i personally understand that only float is the max accuracy available in swift and **there will be no Double**, isn't? Or they have to do something like sudo-Double? Since Apple recommends using Double over Float.

2. For CGFloat: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Cocoa64BitGuide/64BitChangesCocoa/64BitChangesCocoa.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004247-CH4-SW9

> Floating point quantities in the Core Graphics framework (Quartz), which are float on 32-bit architectures, are being expanded to double to provide a wider range and accuracy for graphical quantities. Core Graphics declares a new type for floating-point quantities, CGFloat, and declares it conditionally for both 32-bit and 64-bit

It means that Apple want to take advantage of CPU architecture: 32 or 64 bit to maximize accuracy?

Comment: *"So in 32-bit CPU architecture, ... there will be no Double"* – that is wrong and nowhere stated.

Comment: The runtime on a 32 bit CPU emulates the arithmetic for 64 bit integers and doubles. You can use the data types like on a 64 bit cpu but the computations are slower.

Comment: @macmoonshine: No need to emulate doubles. ARM 32 bit CPUs fully support double precision numbers.

Comment: So how can we interpret that: "Double represents a 64-bit floating-point number. Float represents a 32-bit floating-point number"